Firefox appears to set scrollTop of textarea elements to zero if not displayed and does not restore when displayed?
I realize that when a DOM element is not displayed (or removed from the DOM but still in memory, if that's really a difference) the geometry cannot be accurately queried, and will often return values of zero.
However, when restored to the DOM, the old geometry is restored.
It appears that this is not true in Firefox for textarea elements' scrollTop.
If this snippet is run in Chrome (Brave) the results are 50,0,50,0,50 but in Firefox 50,0,0,0,0. It appears that once a textarea is removed from the DOM its scrollTop is set to zero.
I would like to have the textarea remain at the same scroll position after being temporarily not displayed. I can get (before removing) and set (upon restoring) the value but it produces a tiny jumping in scrolling from 0 to the restored value once displayed.
Is there any way to change this behavior in firefox? It is not a major issue but I'd rather it worked properly.
Thank you.


var
   t = document.querySelector('textarea');
   d = t.parentNode,
   delay = 1000;
t.value ='1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10';
t.scrollTop = 50;
function tran(t) {
 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
   setTimeout( () => {resolve(0);}, t );
 });
}
console.log(t.scrollTop);
tran(delay)
.then( (r) => {
  d.classList.toggle('sel');
  console.log(t.scrollTop);
  return tran(delay);
})
.then( (r) => {
  d.classList.toggle('sel');
  console.log(t.scrollTop);
  return tran(delay);
})
.then( (r) => {
  d.classList.toggle('sel');
  console.log(t.scrollTop);
  return tran(delay);
})
.then( (r) => {
  d.classList.toggle('sel');
  console.log(t.scrollTop);
  return tran(delay);
})
;
div {
  display: none;
}
div.sel {
 display:block;
}
textarea {
 height: 100px;
}
<div class="sel">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>



